# Wordpress twentyfifteen, add custom font using fontface

Tags: wordpress, fonts, font-face

Can anybody please give me detailed directions on how to add a custom free font to wordpress twentyfifteen theme using @font-face, I have selected a free font from fontsquirrel (alex-brush otf) but I am unable to activate the font for the site title, if anybody can provide step by step instructions it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to download a webfont kit (as written on the [license](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/alex-brush#fontface) page), then extract the archive in a folder inside your theme (lets call it `webfont` for now).

Inside the `functions.php` file of you theme, enqueue the kit stylesheet:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'webfont_enqueue_style' );
function webfont_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'webfont', get_template_directory_uri().'/webfont/stylesheet.css', false ); 
}
```

And then you can use it on your site title or wherever with a CSS rule:

```
#siteTitle { font-family: 'WebFont', serif; }
```

Change `WebFont` with the name of the font.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just add this in your main css file for your theme:

```
@font-face {
font-family: fontname;
src: url(LINK_TO_YOUR_FONT);
```

}

and then when you want to use that font use:

```
h1 {
 font-family: fontname;
}
```